# How to format a user entered line?

Tags: c

THIS IS A DIFFERENT QUESTION ENTIRELY. THE OTHER ONE IS URL SPECIFIC MINE IS NOT. THAT WAS JUST AN EXAMPLE.

So here's my code:

```
main()
{
        char input[150];                                                                        //Create a variable of type char named input to store user input

        printf(" Enter a standard line: ");                                                     //Ask the user for some standard input

        if (fgets(input, 150, stdin) == NULL)                                                   //Initiate a series of checks to make sure there is valid input
        {
                puts(" End-of-File or Input Error Detected. ");                                 //If the end of the file is reached or there is a problem with input output a message
        }
        else if (input[0] == '\n')                                                              //If the user neglected to enter anything output a message
        {
                puts(" Oops! Looks like you forgot to enter something! ");
        }
        else
        {
                printf(" Here's what you entered: %s ", input);                                 //If there is valid user input echo it back to the user

            int i = 0;
            while ( input[i] != '\n' )
            {
                    if (input[i] = '/')
                            putchar("%2F");
                    i++

            }

        }
}
```

I have to replace and adjust the input line accordingly by replacing certain characters with their ASCII code.

For example:
1. user inputs: google.COM/search?client
2. program changes and prints back to the user as: GOOGLE.com%2FSEARCH%3FCLIENT

But the system gives me this long error message when I try to compile my code.

```
/home/cs/carroll/cssc0154/One/p1.c: In function 'main':
/home/cs/carroll/cssc0154/One/p1.c:41:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'putchar' makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     putchar("%2F");
     ^
In file included from /home/cs/carroll/cssc0154/One/p1.c:15:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:580:12: note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'char *'
 extern int putchar (int __c);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `"%2F"` is a bit longer than one character...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I understand that. But I'm supposed to replace symbols like "/" with their ASCII codes, so it can't really be helped can it?

Comment: Then use the proper function to print more than one character. You have already used `puts` and `printf`.

Comment: And also... don't you wanna write `if (input[i] == '/')` instead of `if (input[i] = '/')`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I would, if I knew what that was. Which is the entire point of me asking.

Comment: I really don't get what you are asking. You are using functions `puts` and `printf`, meaning that you are obviously aware of their existence and capabilities. Why don't you use one of these to print instead of `putchar`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh! That's what you meant. Because when I used `puts` it replaces the whole sentence and I only want to replace every instance of the one symbol. Though that's probably another problem somewhere in my code.

Comment: Please edit your question - as it is, nobody can use your question in future searches.

Comment: @Fredster Or better yet, `if ('/' == input[i])`.  That way, the compiler will detect the common typo.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass 3 characters '%' '2' 'f' to a function `putchar()` that expects one character.

Consider using 
`printf("%%2f")`
instead of 
`putchar("%2f")`, you'll get the same output in stdout.

Note: you have to escape the percent character in printf with (%).

Comment: So I used `puts("%2f");` but it ended up replacing the whole line and printing out only `%2F`.

Comment: Well that's unexpected. putchar() apparently accepts the character in form of an `int` (usually 4 bytes). You're string: "%2f" has 3 characters and automatically appended terminator '\0' for string literals, that's why you're not getting an error and are probably able to compile. But you're at least getting a warning from the compiler. The result from calling the function `putchar()` that clearly expects one character is unexpected if you pass it more than one.

Comment: Hmm I see. What a conundrum. Well, how about this, do you know how to fold a long line of user input? As in after a certain amount of characters it breaks to a new line.

Comment: While the user is typing? Or after you've received the line in your program? In the 2nd case just create a loop to go through the string received and copy it into a new string inserting a new line character in the position you want.

Comment: After the input has been fully received, stored, and edited accordingly.

Comment: Printing the newline character '\n' takes you to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the points to comment on the above...

Background:

- C doesn't really have 'strings' - it has pointers to characters which it handles very much like arrays.
- standard library functions expect the last value in the array to be '\0', and they will keep processing characters until one of these 'null characters' is read.

This line:

```
putchar("%2F");
```

Passes a pointer (char *) to 'putchar()' instead of an integer.

The warning is simply pointing out the type mismatch, because it's unlikely you meant to do that. (it is correct, this is a **serious** mistake which can crash or cause vulnerabilities depending on the way the called function operates)

Most machines/compilers nowadays are LP64. That means 'putchar()' expects a 32bit integer, and you are providing a 64bit pointer.

The reason this code:

```
int i = 0;
while ( input[i] != '\n' )
{
    if (input[i] == '/')
        puts("%2F");
    i++    
}
```

prints out "%2F" (I assume given the input "google.COM/search?client") is because it finds '/' once, and prints the string you provided "%2F".  No other character executes a print statement.
If you added:

```
int i = 0;
while ( input[i] != '\n' )
{
    if (input[i] == '/')
        puts("%2F");
    else
        putc(intput[i]);
    i++    
}
```

you would get

```
google.COM%2F
search?client
```

because puts() prints a newline ('\n') after printing its input.

To avoid that you'll need to choose a different output function, and while many options are available, printf() is likely the best and certainly the most recognizable.

printf() prints 'formatted' text which uses '%' to indicate formatting options, so printing a single '%' requires you to 'escape' it which looks like "%%"

Here is a working example of what you're trying to do.
I replaced, what must be a large block of

```
if (input[i] == 'CHAR') printf("%%XX");
else if (input[i] == ...
```

by putting all the special characters in a string. 
I simply check whether that string contains each character I'm about to print.

If the character is found, I print a '%' followed by the character's hex value.  The "%02X" tells printf() to write the hex value with at least 2 characters and to put 0 in front if it needs to pad the value.  Basically it will never write '9' but instead write '09'.

You could also use the isalpha() ... isalphanum() ... ispunct() functions to identify which types of characters you should encode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char *decodeStr = "/:\\+";
    int   decodeLen = strlen(decodeStr);

    while(--argc >= 0 && ++argv && *argv){
        char *str = *argv;
        for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
            if (NULL != memchr(decodeStr, str[i], decodeLen))
                printf("%%%02X", str[i]);
            else
                putchar(str[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example run:

```
./test http://google.com/atest+with+things
http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fatest%2Bwith%2Bthings
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much! I'm going to give this a try now!

Comment: So for the purposes of this class I have to use a gcc compiler and apparently it doesn't like for loops. Thanks for your help though. Maybe I can somehow tweak the code so that the gcc compiler likes it lol.

Comment: @Polly gcc shouldn't have any trouble with this.  What error were you getting?  (If it was something about "‘for’ loop initial declarations", try passing `--std=c99` to gcc or moving the declaration of `int i` out of the loop.  The ability to declare variables within loop headers wasn't in the language originally and gcc uses the old standard by default.)

Comment: It was written and tested on GCC 5.4: "gcc test.c -o test "